# How to get clicked link in Windows Phone browser?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

In the Windows Phone web browser I am trying to display a context menu when the user holds down a link(similar to that on IE on windows phone). How can I display a context menu when the user holds down a link in Windows phone browser?

Comment: There are a lot of samples on the web, it's not specific to WP. Could you at least post a few links to what you found but couldn't work it out?

Comment: Most I tried are related to WPF and not compatible with WP8.